# Can't make this glass bottom realistic

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to get this pint glass to have the same bulbous and curvy look as the tutorial I am following but it just won't work.

This is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

And this is how mine looks:

[image]

As you can see there is a lot different between the meshes.  I got the tutorial from blender guru: [Blender Guru](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-beer-blender/#)

I've attached the .blend

[image]

Comment: Have you tried scaling up the rings of vertices closer to the bottom of your mesh until you get your desired result?

Comment: Yes but it looks horrible.  And I have a really hard time selecting inner vertices.

Comment: Yeah I added the lights that come later in the tutorial, but I must've missed something in the tutorial or he didn't explain everything because I've tried to make this glass from scratch several times and I just can't replicate what this guy did.  Also, I'm wondering if there is an inner mesh at all in my glass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm putting my comment here to add images to better explain what I found.

I tried briefly the same tutorial, now.

I'm rendering the result of my short test, I'll post it here soon.
**edit: here it is**

left is with basic diffuse ground plane, right is identical but with glossy ground plane: look at the difference... note: I didn't even add a world hdr, and not even the "fluid" inside... all could add to the result.

[image]

Although render settings in the tut seem to be not disclosed, I think your glass shows a somewhat dim lighting, almost no reflections... why didn't you set the emissions planes off camera?

but mostly the mesh seems to have a weird bottom, and seems to have almost no depth... did you follow closely the modeling workflow?

Look at this image, which I got after bisecting (it is an edit mode tool) your mesh to make more visible the inside...

[image]

I'm sure you've never seen a glass like this...

here is my attempt in comparison:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The bottom was definitely weird!  I started over again and really really scrutinized the tutorial.  There's a video version on youtube as well that explains some things not mentioned in the site link.  However, it looks like I didn't apply the solidify modifier properly to the entire object, as well as learning to select loops with alt + RMB and alt + RMB + shift to select more loops.

Comment: Ohh right I thought you already saw the video, it helps out a lot. Andrew Price is excellent with video tutorials, I have found him useful for too much to recall.